# call method using variables in python

Tags: python

I want to pass methods as variables. In the below method I have 3 methods that are part of the fuzz library. How can I call them using variable name.

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process
method_name1 ='token_sort_ratio'
method_name2 ='partial_ratio'
method_name3 ='ratio'

def compare_alg(l1, l2, alg):
    print(fuzz.alg(l1,l2))

compare_alg("Catherine M Gitau","Catherine Gitau", method_name1)
compare_alg("Catherine M Gitau","Catherine Gitau", method_name2)
compare_alg("Catherine M Gitau","Catherine Gitau", method_name3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr)

```py
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process
method_name1 ='token_sort_ratio'
method_name2 ='partial_ratio'
method_name3 ='ratio'

def compare_alg(l1, l2, alg):
    print(getattr(fuzz, alg)(l1,l2))

compare_alg("Catherine M Gitau","Catherine Gitau", method_name1)
compare_alg("Catherine M Gitau","Catherine Gitau", method_name2)
compare_alg("Catherine M Gitau","Catherine Gitau", method_name3)
```